# Abbreviation list not displaying properly

Tags: glossaries

[image]I am going to make a list of abbreviations and symbols with glossery.tex.

In the text, \gls{} was used, and it comes out without any problems.

However, I don't know why the list of abbreviations and symbols is not sorted like the picture below and no explanation is shown. I wrote the same according to the guidelines of the latex file

I have, but the explanation does not come out. May I ask for some advice?

```
main.tex
\printglossary[type = notation,
        style = symlongcolgrskip,
        nonumberlist] \clearpage

Input_glossary.tex
\newglossaryentry{}{name={}, text={},symbol={\ensuremath{\mathrm{[-]}}}, description={}, type={notation}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.